# Specifying a Entity on a Create Sales Order Entry using Sage Intacct API

Tags: xml, api, post, request, postman

I'm trying to specify a Entity location on a sales order create API where the Entity could be found under Company > Entities. Is there a way to specify it on a Create Sales Order Entry API using Sage Intacct API?

Answer (score 1):

You need to dothis in 2 steps, first query the location using the api location and then pass the value in the sale sorder

1.

```
<query>
    <object>LOCATIONENTITY</object>
    <select>
        <field>LOCATIONID</field>
        <field>NAME</field>
        <field>RECORDNO</field>
    </select>
</query>
```

Result

```
            <result>
                  <status>success</status>
                  <function>query</function>
                  <controlid>controlid</controlid>
                  <data listtype="LOCATIONENTITY" totalcount="1" offset="0" count="1" numremaining="0">
                        <LOCATIONENTITY>
                              <LOCATIONID>100</LOCATIONID>
                              <NAME>Test</NAME>
                              <RECORDNO>1</RECORDNO>
                        </LOCATIONENTITY>
                  </data>
            </result>
      </operation>
</response>
```